# java scan coordinates as (X, Y) format

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I scan coordinates with `(x, y)` format? 
For example:

```
(1, 3) 
(2, 4)
(4, 1)
(3, 2)
```

What I've tried is this:

```
String m = input.next(); 
String parts[] = m.split(","); 

String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1]; 

part1 = part1.substring(1, part1.length()); 
part2 = part2.substring(0, part2.length()-1);
```

That code works for a coordinate with `(x,y)` format but doesn't work for `(x, y)`

Comment: Start by defining "scan". And show us what you tried.

Comment: Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
I tried to do it like input = new Scanner(System.in).delimiter("(,)")
but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: That's a good start. Now start reading stuff from the scanner and parse it. The Scanner and the String javadoc contain useful information.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Why won't you reply to me? We go out of our way to help you and you won't even accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you could get it working with format `(x,y)` but not `(x, y)` with the space in between. I would suggest using `.trim()` to get rid of the spaces:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a coordinate: ");

    String coordinate = input.nextLine();
    String[] parts = coordinate.split(",");

    // if input is (x, y) 
    // then parts[0] is "(x"
    // and parts[1] is " y)"

    String x = parts[0].trim().substring(1).trim();
    String y = parts[1].trim().substring(0, parts[1].trim().length() - 1).trim();

    System.out.println("x: " + x + "\ny: " + y);
}
```

I trimmed the part *before* getting the substring, and then trimmed the part *after* getting the substring as well, so that when the brackets are ignored in the substrings, the spaces will also be removed. It seems to work for all cases no matter how much whitespace there is.

---

Samples:

1. Without a space

   ```
   Enter a coordinate: 
   (155,54)
   x: 155
   y: 54
   ```
2. With a space

   ```
   Enter a coordinate: 
   (118, 43)
   x: 118
   y: 43
   ```
3. With a lot of spaces

   ```
   Enter a coordinate: 
   (  155 , 4   )
   x: 155
   y: 4
   ```

Comment: I appreciate your effort...nice job dude!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline for one way to go about doing this:

1. Instantiate a `Scanner` object.
2. Read the next token (the next line) from it with the `next()` method.
3. Split the read in `String` on the comma and save the resulting array into a `String[]` - e.g. `nums[]`.
4. For the first number, parse the first string in the `String[]` from the 2nd character (at index 1, not 2) onwards into an `int`. You can use `Integer.valueOf()` and `substring(1)` to do this.
5. For the second number, substring from the 1st character of the second string in the `nums[]` array (index 0) until the character before the last character. So `substring(0, nums[1].length()-1)`. Again, use `Integer.valueOf()`.

Hopefully that helps and doesn't completely give away the solution without some more effort on your part. Also, note that you should handle exceptions that might pop up.

Comment: String m = input.next();
String parts[] = m.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
part1 = part1.substring(1, part1.length());
part2 = part2.substring(0, part2.length()-1);
When input is formatted as (x,y) it works. But when user leaves a space after the comma it gives an arrayoutofbounds error.
Thank you for your respond!

Comment: Yes, you'd have to handle that case with some extra logic. Good luck!