# (JAVA) I have to put an char in an array and then i have to move the char(scanner)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have to put an X in the Array and then I have to move the X (left,up,right,down). I think I have to do it with java.util.Scanner. I need help pls.

I created a field with Arrays the Point are field where i can move my X(Player).

rules:
I cant move to a R or O

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int WIDTH = 18;
        final int HEIGHT = 11;
        final int CHAR_COUNT = 30;
        final int PLAYER = 1;
        final int endgame = 1;
        final int PLAYERCOUNTER = 2;
        final char[] CHARS = {
            'R',
            'O'
        };
        final char[] PLAYERPOINTS = {
            'X',
            '+'
        };
        String player = "X";

        // Create field filled with '.'
        char[][] field = new char[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(field[i], '.');


        }

        // the holes and robots (R and O)
        Random random = new Random();
        for (char ch: CHARS) {

            for (int j = 0, x, y; j < CHAR_COUNT; j++) {

                do {
                    x = random.nextInt(WIDTH);

                    y = random.nextInt(HEIGHT);
                } while (field[y][x] != '.');
                field[y][x] = ch;

            }
        }

        //print field
        for (char[] row: field) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row).replaceAll(",", "") + " ");

        }

        //Player
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How can I put a X in the Array and how do i move the X?

Comment: You could [ask for two coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665910/java-scan-coordinates-as-x-y-format) and then set the array value at that point to 'X'.